# How to not expect return code from nohup command from remote

Tags: ssh, shell-script, nohup

env : centos7, lang : bash

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvbVU.png)

If I call `wasctl` from a remote server, `ssh remote1 "./wasctl start"` it hangs forever after running everyjob successfully.

It turns out my ssh call was waiting on a while loop even though the loop runs on background.

---

**restartwas_start.sh**

```
  1 #!/bin/sh
  2 INTERVAL=10
  3 LOG_TIME=`date +'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S'`
  4 RESTARTWAS_PID=`ps -ef|grep "restartwas.sh"| grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'`
  5 if [ -z ${RESTARTWAS_PID} ]; then
  6   nohup ./restartwas.sh &
  7 fi
```

---

**restartwas.sh**

```
  1 #!/bin/sh
  2 INTERVAL=5
  3 while true
  4 do
  5 sleep $INTERVAL
  6     LOG_TIME=`date +'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S'`
  7     ONLINE_JAVA_PID=`ps -ef|grep java|grep "instance.name"|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'`
  8     if [ -z ${ONLINE_JAVA_PID} ]; then
  9        echo $LOG_TIME" was down"
 10        echo $LOG_TIME" was restart start"
 11        ./wasctl start
 12        while true
 13        do
 14           START_JAVA_PID=`ps -ef|grep java|grep "instance.name"|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'`
 15           if [ -n ${START_JAVA_PID} ]; then
 16             break;
 17           fi
 18           sleep 1
 19        done
 20       echo $LOG_TIME" was restart stop"
 21    fi
 22 done
```

---

If I don't call `restartwas_start.sh` the remote call ends normally.
How do I run the loop shell on background and still terminate the call normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In restartwas_start.sh:

`6   nohup ./restartwas.sh &`

Make it:

`6   nohup ./restartwas.sh < /dev/null >& XXXX &`

Here XXXX can be /dev/null, in which case you will not get the echo outputs.
Or XXXX can be /tmp/my_was_script.log or something similar, where the echo outputs will be captured.

This should work.

Problem is that ssh was not exiting because the Processes started by nohup (restartwas.sh & the various commands in that script) were still using the common STDIN STDOUT & STDERR and ssh was waiting for EOF on those.

By redirecting these 3 to /dev/null or to some file, we ensured that ssh is not left waiting.

Reference:
http://www.snailbook.com/faq/background-jobs.auto.html
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Comment: In which order does the command operate? Sorry I'm a noob and I'm having hard time sorting this out in my mind.

Comment: @Lunartist , I have updated the answer with some explanation. Hope that helps.

Comment: So the solution is to provide an empty input to `./restartwas.sh`, I think I got the  `< /dev/null` part, but what is the second redirection for? Is `>& XXXX` essential?

Comment: That is to ignore ( or capture ) output and error ... It is essential, to make `SSH` quit without waiting ...

Comment: @Lunartist , 2 unsolicited comments about your script : **(1)** There is a race condition bug between lines 11 & 12 in restartwas.sh , where wasctl tries to start and immediately crashes; then line 14 will never get the PID and hence the inner while loop will never exit; then it will never try to restart. **(2)** With or without this bug, the inner while loop is unnecessary: When you start wasctl in line 11, you should sleep for N seconds and try to get the PID; If no PID, then wasctl did not start or started and crashed. Then, it should go back to outer while loop and then try to restart.